# PHP Mysql trying to pull multiple rows from different tables (works for 3 rows on 2 tables but not 4 rows from 3 tables)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull multiple rows from different tables in a database.

If I only have the first 3 rows from two tables, it works fine.  As soon as I add the third table and try and pull another row it breaks!

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is pull the image, the `dayid`, the name of a person, and then name of a cause.

The `imageURL` and the `Outfitday_id` are in the same table, the name of the person is in the table `Pilot`, and the name of the cause is in the table cause.

For some reason it will pull the first two rows (`imageUrl`, `outfitDay_id`) from the table `Outfitimage`, then pull the 3rd row (`name`) from `Pilot`, but fails if I add the name and try and pull it from the `Cause` table.

```
$link = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
if ($link) {
   mysql_selectdb("up",$link);  
   // Select records from the DB  
   $query  = "SELECT imageUrl,outfitDay_id,name,name FROM OutfitImage,Pilot,Cause ORDER BY Rand(" . date("Ymd") . ") LIMIT 1";
   $image = mysql_query($query);

   // Display records from the table  
   echo "";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($image, MYSQL_NUM)) {
      echo "<IMAGE SOURCE='$row[0]'/><br>";
      echo "<div id='info'>Day $row[1] of ";
      echo "$row[2] Uniform Project for$row[3] </div>";
   }
   echo "";
} else {
    echo "Can't connect to the database!";
}
```

Comment: Why, I just wrote a really lengthy question and answer that covers this exact [sort of question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which I hope will help to clarify how joins work on tables and how to get information from multiple tables in your database!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for commenting on this thread…that was a great write-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably happens because the `name` column is ambiguous. I'm guessing you have a `name` column in both the `Cause` and `Pilot` (or some other table). MySQL can't guess what table you want to retrieve the column value from, and will spit an error (*Column name in field list is ambiguous*).

Make sure you prefix the column name with the table name to remove ambiguity:

```
SELECT 
   imageUrl, outfitDay_id, Cause.name, Pilot.name 
FROM 
   OutfitImage, Pilot, Cause
```

Comment: $query  = "SELECT OutfitImage.imageUrl,OutfitImage.outfitDay_id,Pilot.name,Cause.name  FROM OutfitImage,Pilot,Cause ORDER BY Rand(" . date("Ymd") . ") LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting a cross-join across all three tables, but you aren't creating any conditions to filter them out.  The clause FROM table1, table2, table3 attempts a cross-join across all three tables.  A cross-join means every row from one table is paired up with every row from another table.  For example, say I have three tables, each have two rows.  The first table I call names with the two rows jack and jill, the second table I will call ages with rows 21 and 24, the third table will be genders, and have rows male and female.  If I do a clause FROM names, ages, genders, it will return a table with 2 X 2 X 2 = 8 rows.

```
names ages genders
jack  21   male
jack  21   female
jack  24   male
jack  24   female
jill  21   male
jill  21   female
jill  24   male
jill  24   female
```

Normally, when you cross-join, you also add a condition to WHERE to filter out rows that don't make sense.  For example, from example FROM clause you might have a WHERE genders.id = names.genders_id.  In this case, you are linking a name with a specific gender row from the genders table.  This will probably also solve your need for a LIMIT 1.